# Why is swaplevel() slow in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

Why is [`swaplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) slow in Pandas? In fact, why wouldn't it simply swap the two relevant lists in the index [levels and labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#defined-levels) (and swap level names)?

The slowness is obvious, with about 100,000 columns in a MultiIndex, but is it necessary? The documentation for `swaplevel()` doesn't indicate that this method does anything special in addition to swapping the levels.

Comment: But it seems that it has to reconstruct a df with a new multi-index, isn't this the reason? If it was just returning the index but swapped then this would not be so taxing. How does the time compare with `df.copy()`?

Comment: There is in principle no need to reconstruct a dataframe, though: a row that was defined by label numbers, say, (1, 2, 3) (corresponding to ("Apple", "2018-08-08", 15)) would simply become defined as having label numbers (1, 3, 2) (corresponding to ("Apple", 15, "2018-08-08")). This can be achieved simply by swapping the last two lists of index levels and labels. The copy does take about the same time (about 15 seconds). Furthermore, the dataframe `values` do not have the same `id()` and are thus not the same. On the other hand, they looks identical.

Comment: This is all true but it's just not implemented that way, most pandas ops return a copy of the data, this looks no different to me. It could be optimised by calculating the new index and then constructing a df taking the np values as the data and passing the swapped levels as the new index. You could post an issue on github

Comment: My thought process on the above is that if the `data` arg is a numpy array then `pandas` can optimise the blockmanager by taking a view on the data but you'd have to try this

Comment: Issue submitted: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22246